# Software suggestion: hand tracing photo to vector on tablet

Tags: vector, software-recommendation, android, applications, tracing

I am looking for software that let's me *trace* a photo by hand on an android device and then have the result saved as vectors (EPS, SVG, whatever).

The task is trivial

The only reference I could find was "morpholio", but that seems to be available for iOS only. (And trust me, I had a *very* thorough look around the PlayStore).

Basically, I would like to use my android tablet as a poor-mans' Wacom.

Comment: What about Adobe's [Illustrator Draw app](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Adobe%20Draw&hl=en_US)?

Comment: Could you use a desktop computer and a mouse...? I personally don't quite see the benefit with using a drawing tablet for tracing photos into vector. I would just use pen tool and a mouse, but it's not a thing that I've done a lot anyways so what do I know. Like if you're tracing like a tree with bunch of leaves, you'd probably lose your mind using a pen tool to trace every single leaf, but... yea... Just kinda mapping out the need here.

Comment: You can add an image layer in the app.  Go to the layers, click + on the right to add a new layer - choose Image layers.

Comment: @Joonas Well, I tried it already on desktop with a mouse and it works, but I find it a bit clumsy. So I hope this approach will work better. I wish it were trees or flowers, but it's cars.

Comment: Oh I'd totally use pen tool for tracing cars. And I'm super not a fan of stylus and pen tool together. Trying to click a specific point as the cursor shifts when you put the stylus down... So frustrating.

Comment: As for a poor man's Wacom, what about one of Wacom's entry level graphics tablets? They're not so expensive.  I use an old Wacom Bamboo model, which works just fine for me when I need to draw anything freehand in Illustrator or Inkscape.

Comment: The Wacom Intuous S seems to be the cheapest new model currently available.  Here in the UK you can buy if for about £57. Perhaps even look on ebay for a second hand one.

Comment: @BillyKerr, but would you draw, or more specifically trace a car from a photo with a drawing tablet freehand? That's the part that I'm interested in. How is OP going to do that... I guess if it's a very specific style (maybe a sketch) it could work...

Comment: @Joonas Sure, it would be more of a sketch type drawing which is what I meant by a "freehand" drawing,   If you want precisely placed lines and curves, I think using mouse and the Pen Tool would probably be better, although I've seen people use the Pen Tool with a Wacom too, I can't honestly see the point of that myself. Each to his own.

Comment: @Joonas I was hoping that I could get reasonably good Bezier curves this way, that I could later edit if needed in Illustrator. With the Draw app, I do indeed get vectors, but they are all 'thick outlines'. I can indeed only achieve a sketchy look this way.

Comment: @Ideogram, mmm... That is some sketchy stuff you're doing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Adobe Illustrator Draw app. It works on Android devices, and is available in the Google Play store.

To add an image, begin a new project. Tap the Layers icon, tap the + icon to add a new layer. Choose "Image Layer", select an image from your gallery or take a photo, or use select one from your cloud files, etc.

If you tap on the image layer icon, you can set the layer opacity low, so you can trace over it.

When you have finished, press the Upload icon, and send the project to Adobe Illustrator (desktop version) - make sure you have the application open already on your computer before doing this, and from there you can export as SVG, or whatever format you want.  Obviously you'd need to have an Adobe CC account for this last step.

Comment: Indeed, it works. I have no idea why I couldn't find that first. Thanks!

Comment: @Ideogram great!